# Xamarin Forms: System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, idisposable

I get an ObjectDisposedException when a list item's property is changed from another screen.
Here's my renderer code.

```
namespace SmartwebsCrossPlatform.CustomRenderers {
    public class GradientViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer {
        View cellCore;

        protected override View GetCellCore( Cell item, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context ) {
            cellCore = base.GetCellCore( item, convertView, parent, context );
            DirtyChanged();
            return cellCore;
        }

        protected override void OnCellPropertyChanged( object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e ) {
            base.OnCellPropertyChanged( sender, e );
            if (e.PropertyName == "IsDirty" )
                DirtyChanged();
        }

        void DirtyChanged(  ) {
            var viewCell = Cell as GradientViewCell;
            if( cellCore != null && viewCell != null) {
                int r = viewCell.IsDirty
                    ? Resource.Drawable.listViewGradientDirty
                    : Resource.Drawable.listViewGradient;
                try {
                    cellCore.SetBackgroundResource( r );
                } catch ( ObjectDisposedException ex ) {
                    Log.Warning( ex, "GradientViewCellRenderer.DirtyChanged" );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Question: how do I detect if cellCore has been disposed in DirtyChanged?

Answer (score 0):

After searching online , I didn't found a good way to detect an `IDisposable` Object .

To avoid the unnecessary dispose ,We can try to change the GC Bridges to see if it works.

- Create a `environment.text` file within your `Xamarin.Android` project with the `BuildAction` set to `AndroidEnvironment`.
- Then you can specify which `GC_BRIDGE` option your application should use by passing `bridge-implementation=old`, `bridge-implementation=new`, or `bridge-implementation=tarjan` to the `MONO_GC_PARAMS` environment variable.

Refer to https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-android-garbage-collection-improvements/